# MiniProfiler is bypassing my Authorization filter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc-mini-profiler

I have mini-profiler working, but now I am trying to restrict access by setting functions as described under "Profiler Security" at http://miniprofiler.com/

```
MiniProfiler.Settings.Results_Authorize = IsUserAllowedToSeeMiniProfilerUI;
MiniProfiler.Settings.Results_List_Authorize = IsUserAllowedToSeeMiniProfilerUI;
```

My `IsUserAllowedToSeeMiniProfilerUI` function needs to look at the results of the ClaimsPrincipal, which is modified by a custom globally registered Authorization filter.

When I watch the calls, the primary request is authorized as expected, and `IsUserAllowedToSeeMiniProfilerUI` returns true.  However, the http request that retrieves the profiler results (`~/mini-profiler-resources/results` or `~/mini-profiler-resources/results-index`) bypasses my global authorization filter, so the ClaimsPrincipal isn't correctly modified for that request, and `IsUserAllowedToSeeMiniProfilerUI` incorrectly returns `false` due to that.

I register mini-profiler's filter as `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new ProfilingActionFilter())`, and also have the handler registered in the web.config as

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="MiniProfiler" path="mini-profiler-resources/*" verb="*"
       type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" 
       resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
<!-- ... -->      
</handlers>
```

My custom authorization filter is registered in the Global.asax by adding it as `GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyAuthorizationFilter())`

Why is mini-profiler bypassing my authorization filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GlobalFilters` is centric to the MVC framework.  So by default the globally registered authorization filters will only take effect for requests handled by the mvc framework - not for all http requests.

MiniProfiler implements its client-side results in a single class `MiniProfilerHandler` that implements both [`IRouteHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.iroutehandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`IHttpHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  (The default profiler provider `WebRequestProfilerProvider` ensures that the routes for `MiniProfilerHandler` are registered.  The web.config registration of UrlRoutingModule ensures that the mini profiler urls are actually routed.)

Thus mini profiler handles the profiler results http requests directly as an http handler that is located by routing - outside of the normal MVC request flow.

So it is necessary to handle any custom authorization logic in the e.g. `IsUserAllowedToSeeMiniProfilerUI` method taking into account that any authorization filters (or other action filters for that matter) are not guaranteed to have run.  Note however, that it appears that `Results_Authorize` is also invoked at some stage once profiling is started, so you also must handle the case where your filters *have* run.

See also: [Understanding the MVC Application Execution Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381612%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)